# How to find element in nested span using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on 'New Trade' link which is in span n6 which is a child element of span n2. I am able to reach till n2 but its not identifying 'n6'.
Please help I am new to Selenium WebDriver

Here I am posting the html and my code.

> Trading
>
> New
>   Trade
>
> Trade
>   Explorer

I want to click on **New Trade**

[HTML source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KP3MA.png)

My code which went till span 'n2':

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("treeFrame")));

WebElement allFormChildElements = driver.findElement(By.name("the_form"));
allFormChildElements.findElement(By.linkText("Trading")).click();  

WebElement modalDialog = allFormChildElements.findElement(By.className("border"));
WebElement newmodalDialog = modalDialog.findElement(By.className("formScrollableMenuContent")); 
System.out.println(newmodalDialog.findElements(By.tagName("a")).size()); // ans 5 

WebElement newDialog= newmodalDialog.findElement(By.id("n2"));
System.out.println(newDialog.findElements(By.id("n3")).size()); // ans 0
```

Comment: Try xpath as suggested by @Aarya.

Comment: I tried using xpath allFormChildElements.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),\"New Trade\")]")).click(); but its not working :(.

Comment: Try : driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),"New Trade")]")); OR  try driver.findElemenet(By.linkText("New Trade"));

Comment: I tried both but its not working :(

Comment: Put the code in try catch and try to see the error. You can see the error in console. Simple debugging stuff.

Comment: I tried and getting NoSuchElementException

Comment: Try putting webdriverwait.

Comment: sometimes its clicking the node by driver.cssselector("#n6 > a").click(); and sometime not. any idea?

Comment: @Kritika could you share the hmtl? (instead of the image)

Comment: I am unable to copy paste html. Its not selecting, Please tell me where you have confusion in html image, Will check and let you know

Comment: as per your question, your are trying to identify n6, but it is n3 in your code. is it typo? please check the last line of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the image I can't test but, if you are able to reach the element `<span id="n2">`, from there you could use the following xpath in order to click the element with the text "New Trade":

```
newDialog.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[@id='n6']/a[@name='A6' and text()='New Trade']")).click();
```

**EDIT**

If the id value change, try in this way:

```
newDialog.findElement(By.xpath(".//span/a[@name='A6' and text()='New Trade']")).click();
```

Comment: This is working absolutely fine but the only problem is id value is dynmaic , sometimes its n6 and sometime n26, Can you please guide me what can i do in this case so that same logic i can apply on nested elements inside n6. Also when I am trying to print the total spans inside id = n2, Its giving 0. Please suggest.

Comment: Its working fine and using this I am able to access nested elements inside New Trade as well. Thanks a lot. one last time can you please spare some time to help me on this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47092830/how-to-open-a-save-dialog-popup-in-ie11-using-robot.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try below  xpath

```
//a[contains(text(),"New Trade")]
```

Comment: I tried using xpath allFormChildElements.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),\"New Trade\")]")).click(); but its not working :(.