# What should be the css selector for <p class="subheading">Enter Optionality</p>

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

I have tried various css statements but its not working,

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p:class(subheading{"EnterOptionality"}")).isDisplayed();
```

Can any one guide on this?

Comment: Not entirely sure what language that is, but `p:class(subheading{"EnterOptionality"}` is not a valid CSS selector - you cannot select by content. Also, the parentheses don't match, and I have my doubts about the nested quotes.

Comment: What JS library are you using? That is no standard CSS or JS.

Comment: This is Selenium, right? Better add the tag for that.

Comment: yea, added tag selenium.

Comment: i used xpath also to find the element for driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[text() = 'Enter Optionality']")) but thats also not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select this:

```
<p class="subheading">Enter Optionality</p>
```

**CSS**:

```
driver.findElementByCssSelector("p.subheading").click();
```

**XPATH**:

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//p[@class='subheading' and text()='Enter Optionality']").click();
```

Comment: I didn't try your CSS solution because there are many "p : subheading" classes with different innertext. But I tried xpath solution and its working fine. Thanks a lot :)..Also can you please check my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46905917/how-to-find-element-in-nested-span-using-selenium-webdriver.. and give me some answer if possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As @davide answer is correct but i want to add something. if there is 'Enter Optionality' text in webpage you can sue simple xpath like this:

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//p[contains(text(),'Enter Optionality']").click();
```

OR

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//*[contains(text(),'Enter Optionality']").click();
```